# Springboot starter for Apache Camel (AMQP) doesn't find ConnectionFactory bean

Tags: apache-camel, spring-amqp, spring-camel

I created an application to read messages from Apache qpid and to send them on Apache kafka. I am using Camel with Springboot starter. My Pom looks like this -

```
<dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Camel BOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ... other BOMs or dependencies ... -->
    </dependencies>

</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>
    <!-- starters -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-amqp-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-kafka-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- other camel dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and Spring application class is -

```java
@SpringBootApplication
    public class CamelSpringJmsKafkaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CamelSpringJmsKafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory(@Value("${qpidUser}") String qpidUser, @Value("${qpidPassword}") String qpidPassword, @Value("${qpidBrokerUrl}") String qpidBrokerUrl) {
        JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory = new JmsConnectionFactory(qpidPassword, qpidPassword, qpidBrokerUrl);
        return jmsConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CachingConnectionFactory jmsCachingConnectionFactory(JmsConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);

        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }
```

application.properties is -

```
camel.springboot.main-run-controller = true
camel.component.amqp.enabled = true
camel.component.amqp.connection-factory = jmsCachingConnectionFactory
camel.component.amqp.async-consumer = true
camel.component.amqp.concurrent-consumers = 1
camel.component.amqp.map-jms-message = true
camel.component.amqp.test-connection-on-startup = true
camel.component.kafka.brokers = localhost:9092
qpidBrokerUrl = amqp://localhost:5672?jms.username=guest&jms.password=guest&jms.clientID=clientid2&amqp.vhost=default
qpidUser = guest
qpidPassword = guest
```

RouteBuilder is -

```java
    @Component
    public class QpidToKafkaRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("amqp:queue:test")
                .log("Received key : ${header.JMSMessageID}, message : ${body}")
                .setHeader(KafkaConstants.KEY, header("JMSMessageID"))
                .to("kafka:camel")
                .log("Sent key : ${headers[kafka.KEY]}, message : ${body}");
    }
    }
```

When I start this application, it throws following exception -

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route1 because of null
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:125) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: connectionFactory must be specified
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:152) ~[camel-util-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1629) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getOrCreateConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:773) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createListenerConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:1638) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.getOrCreateListenerConnectionFactory(JmsConfiguration.java:816) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.configureMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:1468) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsConfiguration.java:725) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createMessageListenerContainer(JmsEndpoint.java:189) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:184) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsEndpoint.createConsumer(JmsEndpoint.java:73) ~[camel-jms-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.addServices(DefaultRoute.java:560) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultRoute.onStartingServices(DefaultRoute.java:166) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:153) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123) ~[camel-base-3.4.0.jar:3.4.0]
```

Could you please help suggest why during autoconfiguring Springboot is not finding connectionFactory? When I debug this code, I can see connectionFactory bean is getting created. I can even see one more log line -

```
CamelContext has only been running for less than a second. If you intend to run Camel for a longer time then you can set the property camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true in application.properties or add spring-boot-starter-web JAR to the classpath.
```

however if you see my application.properties file, required property is present at the very beginning.

One more log, I can see at the beginning of application startup -

```
[main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Note - One intresting fact that exactly same code was running fine last night, just restarted my desktop and there is not even a single word changed and now it is throwing exception. Code can also be seen here - https://github.com/prashantbhardwaj/qpid-to-kafka-using-camel

Comment: It might be too late, i noticed that @Bean for JmsConnectionFactory argument uses password for the username value. hope u have already solved this.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, but value of username and password is same, so this is not an issue.